# Kubernetes ingress block in creating state

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have deployed an app with Google Kubernetes Engine. All function works perfectly but I have a strange problem. If I check the status in Google cloud console the ingress is always in creating phase.

You can see it in image:

[image]

Have you some suggestion to resolve it?

Thanks

[EDIT]

```
kubectl describe ingress: 
Name:             ++++++-nginx-ingress
Namespace:        ++++++
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.4.0.4:8080)
Rules:
  Host                        Path  Backends
  ----                        ----  --------
  ++++++-back.*******.net
                                 ++++++-nginx-np:80 (<none>)
  ++++++.*******.net
                                 ++++++-front-np:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:                    {"k8s-be-30141--93abcf3e6a0e0671":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32338--93abcf3e6a0e0671":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32589--93abcf3e6a0e0671":"HEALTHY"}
  ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map:                     k8s-um-++++++-++++++-nginx-ingress--93abcf3e6a0e0671
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http":"false","kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name":"++++++-nginx-ingress-ip"},"labels":{"app":"++++++-nginx-ingress"},"name":"++++++-nginx-ingress","namespace":"++++++"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"++++++-back.*******.net","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"++++++-nginx-np","servicePort":80}}]}},{"host":"++++++.*******.net","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"++++++-front-np","servicePort":80}}]}}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http:             false
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:  ++++++-nginx-ingress-ip
Events:   

                                  <none>
```

YAML file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: ++++++-nginx-ingress
 labels:
   app: ++++++-nginx-ingress
 annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ++++++-nginx-ingress-ip
     kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
 namespace: ++++++
spec:
 rules:
 - host: ++++++-back.++++++.net
   http:
     paths:
     - backend:
         serviceName: ++++++-nginx-np
         servicePort: 80
 - host: ++++++.++++++.net
   http:
     paths:
     - backend:
         serviceName: ++++++-front-np
         servicePort: 80
```

Comment: there are different root cause why the ingress stuck in creating status, can you past the ingress yaml file from the console ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl describe ingress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking your output I can see that the loadbalncer is not created or not getting your static IP `++++++-nginx-ingress-ip` normally after the `Spec.Backend`

```
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

On thing the Annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"` is used when TLS for the ingress is configured.

Another thing you may check if the Add-on for **L7 HTTP load balancing** is Enabled by default when creating the cluster is enabled